# Screen "freeze" when switching view controllers in iOS 9.2

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9, viewcontroller, freeze

I saw this performance regression using SpriteKit in iOS 9.1 and was hoping this would be resolved in 9.2 but it is not.  (Worked fine in iOS 8)  There is a slight (1s) screen freeze when switching between view controllers.  I am using buttons and segues in the storyboard to transition between VCs.  The screen freeze coincides with this error message:

2015-12-09 19:53:06.991 Game7[411:91125] : calling -display has no effect.

I have read about explicitly setting the zpositions of all sprite nodes to improve performance but this does not seem to help.  Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: post some code,  particularly code involving the segue

Comment: I don't have much code since I'm using storyboards. However I just removed the animations on my storyboard segues and the screen freeze is gone.  I did this in the Attributes Inspector just by unchecking "Animates".  (Kind = Show (e.g. Push))  So I'm guessing the SKMetalLayer warning has no impact.

Comment: if it is failing due to animation,  then you are not pausing your objects on the old screen that could be affecting the animation,  and thats why it may be locking up on you

Comment: I will look into that.  Thanks.